# Displaying number of rows checked/unchecked on datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid on a form with a checkbox to select all records. Column (0) of my datagrid is a checkbox column, and on the header I put a checkbox to select all records and display the number of records selected. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub chkSelectRecords_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkSelectRecords.CheckedChanged

        'Procedure runs when the checkSelectRecords is clicked.
        'The loop selects all records on the datagrid when checked
        'and clears selection when unchecked.

        Dim chkRow As Integer = 0

        If chkSelectRecords.Checked = True Then

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDeleteRecord.Rows

                row.Cells(0).Value = (row.Cells(0).Value IsNot DBNull.Value)
                chkRow += 1

                lblRowCount.Visible = True
                lblRowCount.Text = chkRow.ToString & " Record(s) Selected"
           Next
        Else
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDeleteRecord.Rows

                row.Cells(0).Value = (row.Cells(0).Value Is DBNull.Value)
                chkRow += 0

                lblRowCount.Text = chkRow.ToString & " Record(s) Selected"
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

I placed another procedure when the user selects one record at a time:

```
Private Sub grdDeleteRecord_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdDeleteRecord.CellContentClick

' Shows how to get count of checked or unchecked checkbox column count along with
' how to get column data back for checked items.

Dim chkRowCount As Integer = 0

grdDeleteRecord.EndEdit()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDeleteRecord.Rows

    If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then
        chkRowCount += 1
    Else
        chkRowCount += 0

        lblRowCount.Visible = True
        lblRowCount.Text = chkRowCount.ToString & " Record(s) Selected"

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Both procedures work as needed. The problem is when I select all records my label does not update the number of records that are now selected. I am sure this is happening because they are two separate events, I just don't know how to link the events or write a procedure that accomplishes all three tasks

Comment: FWIW, the DataGrid is a different control than the DataGridVIEW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I wrote for you. You must use the CellValueChangedEvent and the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged events...

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblRowCount.Text = SetLabel()
 End Sub


Private Function SetLabel() As String
    Dim strRows As String = String.Empty
    Dim intRows As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To grdDeleteRecord.Rows.Count - 1
       If CBool(grdDeleteRecord(0, i).Value) Then
          intRows += 1
       End If
    Next

    If intRows > 0 Then
        strRows = intRows.ToString & " Record(s) Selected"
        lblRowCount.Visible = True
    End If

    Return strRows
End Function

Private Sub grdDeleteRecord_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdDeleteRecord.CellValueChanged
    lblRowCount.Text = SetLabel()
End Sub

Private Sub grdDeleteRecord_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdDeleteRecord.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If grdDeleteRecord.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        grdDeleteRecord.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

When you check or uncheck these checkboxes it will trigger this event and thus update your label. Then you can use this where ever you need it to be used.