# How do I trigger a GridView_CellContentClick event?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a WinForms application. Inside a DataGridView, I have generated a checkbox column dynamically using the following code:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn myCheckedColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "My column",
        FalseValue = 0,
        TrueValue = 1,
        Visible = true
    };

mydatagridview.Columns.Insert(0, myCheckedColumn);
```

When I click on a checkbox, I want to perform validation checks as only a single checkbox gets checked, rather than multiple checkboxes.

I tried to use event `mydatagridview_CellContentClick` but i could not able to trigger this event.

I have written the event code like so:

```
private void mydatagridview_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value))
        {
            int currentcolumnclicked = e.ColumnIndex;
            int currentrowclicked = e.RowIndex;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in associatinggridView.Rows)
            {
                dr.Cells[currentcolumnclicked].Value = false;
            }

            associatinggridView.CurrentRow.Cells[currentrowclicked].Value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you hooked up the event??? (paste the event name `mydatagridview_CellContentClick` into the proper slot in the event tab of the DGV's property panel!)

Comment: can not repro. how DGV is populated?

Comment: You have no handle on your `dgv_CellContentClick` ... Unless you manually set it on form load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the CellValueChangedEvent and the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged events... please see my answer here, its in vb but you just need the events.

[Displaying number of rows checked/unchecked on datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563773/displaying-number-of-rows-checked-unchecked-on-datagridview/21564547#21564547)